# Bukkit plugin for controlling where portals teleport you

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I want to use normal Minecraft portals as a way of people to teleport around my world, but I can't find a plugin that does this. Any ideas?

Comment: I think Runecraft might help you. You can build runes of teleportation that binds two places based on a "signature key" (being the components of the rune and their place in it). Sorry I'm at work so I can't find a link but searching Runecraft would be okay I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [Multiverse-Netherportals](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/multiverse-netherportals/) is as close to what you want as you're going to get:

> ### Multiverse-NetherPortals Features
>
> - Allow a nether per real world!
> - Let nether portals built in a world go to a specific world

Comment: I use Multiverse (and its extensions) on my server and I must say this is the best plugin to do that, and much more. (Portals with other frames, or no frames at all, multiworld support, etc)